# cross-compiling pistache with yocto sdk

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I try to build [pistache](https://github.com/oktal/pistache) with yocto generated SDK.

but I face this error:

```
pistache/src/common/os.cc: In lambda function:
pistache/include/pistache/common.h:48:3: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘(’ token
   (void)0
```

did anyone face it? did anyone fix it?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by removing ;(void)0 from the end of [TRY_RET](https://github.com/oktal/pistache/blob/73f248acd6db4c53e6604577b7e13fd5e756f96f/include/pistache/common.h#L48) definition.